# Error al insertar imagen de fondo en un formulario de windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms, imagen, bitmap

queria saber por que me da este error al tratar de poner una imagen de fondo en un formulario de windows form. He visto como 3 tutoriales donde ponen el mismo codigo y no les da error, agradeceria mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

No lo quiero poner directamente en las propiedades del formulario porque tengo entendido que ahi no puedo indicarle a la imagen que se ajuste al tamaño del formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Casi seguro que no está encontrando el archivo. Asegurate de que la ruta que le pasas es correcta.Cual es la ruta del archivo ' Huellitas.jpg'  actualmente?

Comment: Dale clic en "Copiar detalles de la excepción en el Portapapeles" y **[edit] tu pregunta** con los detalles de la excepción.

Comment: Sinque puedes configurar cómo se va a adaptar la imágen en el formulario. ¿y si el usuario borra el archivo? lo mejor sería tenerlo incrustado en el proyecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías trabajar de esta manera:

```
// Metodo para convertir byte a Image
public Image DeByteImagen(string rutaImagen)
{      
      MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(rutaImagen));
      Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
      return returnImage;
}
```

Al cargar el formulario (en el método Load)

```
this.BackgroundImage = DeByteImagen(Application.StartupPath + @"\img\Huellitas.jpg");
this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Comment: Y...para que complicarse la vida así cuando `new Bitmap` es suficiente? El código que el op tiene es perfectamente válido, el problema es casi seguro que la ruta a su archivo jpg es errónea

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo tranquilamente desde las propiedades. Primero agrega la imagen en la propiedad `BackgroundImage` y luego la ajustas con la propiedad `BackgroundImageLayout = Stretch` por ejemplo. Saludos!